# Install Mongo db with composer

Tags: mongodb, composer-php

I have a problem on an dependency installation.

I work on a app who run under php 7 but i've a probleme to correcty install mongodb.

I'm using composer and my require are write like this :

```
"require": {
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "^3.1",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
    "mustache/mustache": "~2.10"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "uuid": "custom/uuid",
        "RestServer": "custom/RestServer"
    }
}
```

}

I've add extension=mongodb.so in my php ini like this :

```
; Extensions

MAMP_apc_MAMP
extension=imap.so
;extension=gettext.so
extension=mcrypt.so
;extension=yaz.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=mongodb.so
```

when I'm going to update my composer I have this message :

```
➜  classes php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I don't understand who's gone wrong. Can you help me devs friends??

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu? Have you rebooted system/restarted the service after modifying php.ini?

Comment: Hi Dorad and thank's to answer me! I'm running on mac osx and i've restarted the service and reboot but i've the same problem...

Comment: No... i've the same message...

Comment: I think you have to use the following command:
"pecl install mongodb".
look here(also in the comment):
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php
or here if it's not working: http://manas.tungare.name/blog/how-to-install-mongodb-for-php-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: I've found the problem, there are two files php.ini. A general file who's put in the MAMP folder and a specific file when you do on MAMP file/updatemodele/php/php7.0.0.php.ini. In this two files we do add extension=mongodb.so

Comment: Really Thank you Dorad!

Comment: You're welcome. I am Glad you solved it.